# Android : Push Notification via C2DM

Tags: android, push-notification, android-c2dm

I am going to do push notification for my app. Is it possible to check this push notification for the application which is not in android market. give me suggestions on how to do test.

Comment: what you want? clear your requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need publish the application on the Android market to use C2DM - [here](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/android/c2dm/) is official tutorial

Comment: then how could i give the path for my app can i use my local ip address...........

Comment: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html - this tutorial will also help you.

Comment: just create 2.2 emulator, you should have no problem with this